# Have a Search Activity return a result?

Tags: android, search, listactivity

Hi I was wondering how I can get my Search Activity to return a result back to the Activity that started it.

I currently have a Search Dialog implemented (meaning the search Activity starts once the Search button on the phone is clicked).

Here is my code for the Search activity which is a list view.

public class ItemFinder extends ListActivity {

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1; // get it?
Vector<String> upcCodes;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search);

    upcCodes = new Vector<String>();

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {              
            String upc = upcCodes.elementAt(position);

            setResult(RESULT_OK);
        }
    });

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

      ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ItemFinder.this, "Searching", 
              "Searching. Please wait...", true);

      performSearch(query);

      dialog.hide();
      dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

public void performSearch(String query){    
    String result = new SmartShopClient().SearchItems(query);
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String _parsedResult[] = result.split("\\n");
    for( int i = 0; i<_parsedResult.length; i++){
        String _splitData[] = _parsedResult[i].split("\\|");
        String itemName = _splitData[0];
        String itemUPC = _splitData[1];
        dataList.add(itemName);
        upcCodes.add(itemUPC);
    }              

    ArrayAdapter<String> arr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);
    this.setListAdapter(arr);

}
```

}

So the search is working all fine and dandy, but I want it so when I click one of the results in the ListView, for it to return data back to the main activity with some data, say the name of the clicked searched result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is launch the search using `startActivityForResult`.  See an explanation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

This way, you can pass your search results back to the activity which launched it.

Comment: After implementing this approach, the problem with it is that onSearchRequested is called even before any input is put into the box. Therefore the search works and the result is returned by my search query always defaults to "Null"

Answer (score 1):

That would happen in your `setOnItemClickListener` method, where you could launch an explicit intent naming the desired activity with extra data.

**Edit :** I'm not quite sure of how `startActivityForResult()` would be implemented since we're talking about the search activity of the application, meaning it's launched by the Android search specific module ; that's why i suggested the above solution.

Comment: The problem with starting a new activity, is I want to give data the the previous activity. I don't want to start a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

```
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    askSearchQuery();
    return true;
}

public void sendSearchRequest(String query){
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, ItemFinder.class);
    mIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
    mIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    startActivityForResult(mIntent, ItemFinder.REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void askSearchQuery() {
    final EditText input = new EditText(SmartShop.this);
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(SmartShop.this);
    adb.setTitle("Search Items");
    adb.setMessage("Please input the name of the item you are looking for.");
    adb.setView(input);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {          

            Editable upc = input.getText(); 
            sendSearchRequest(upc.toString());

            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    adb.create().show();
}
```

And then I hooked the

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
```